# Gradient of the trace of the logarithm of a product

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, differential-operators

Suppose $G$ and $A$ are full rank matrices. Is there a closed-form solution for

$$\nabla_G \mbox{Tr} (A \log GG^\top)$$

when $A$ is a PSD matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by "closed form"?

Comment: unless $A=I$ this is a complicated calculation because you need to take the derivative of the logarithm of a matrix, see for example this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231635/derivative-of-matrix-logarithm-w-r-t-real-parameter); for $A=I$ the answer is just ${\rm Tr}\,(1/G+1/G^t)$.

Comment: Write the series for $\log$ and differentiate each term: Differentiating a power needs $D_{A,X} A^n = XA^{n-1} + AXA^{n-2} +\dots+A^{n-1}X$ (for the directional derivative with respect to the variable $A$ in direction $X$), since the matrices do not commute. Passing to the gradient needs an inner product on the space of matrices. $\text{Tr}(XY^\top)$ is a suitable one.